# Converting PPTx slides to images format using python

Tags: python-pptx

I am looking for a python code to iterate through a folder directory which has PPT files, which I need to convert them (specific number of slides) to image files and save them with respective slide numbers.

```
ppt_path = r"C://Users//RamJst/Documents/Test1.pptx"
Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")

Presentation = Application.Presentations.Open(ppt_path, ReadOnly=True, WithWindow=False)
Presentation.Slides\[1\].Export(ppt_path, "JPG")
Application.Quit()
```

The above code gives me below error when I attempt to convert a single PPT.
[image]